# How to write if conditions inside if with one else in bash

Tags: bash

Im sorry if my question is wrong.

Here is my code.

```
   if [[ "$http_status" -ne 200 ]]; then
       # curl command to check the response
       http_status= some response

       if [[ "$http_status" -ne 200 ]]; then
           # curl command to check the response
           http_status= some response

           if [[ "$http_status" -ne 200 ]]; then
               # curl command to check the response
               http_status= some response
               echo "Some error. Please try again"
           fi
       fi
   else
      echo "You got the response"
   fi
```

Is it possible to use only one else for 3 if statements?
Say, if my 2nd if condition is true (if i got response in 2nd if), will it execute else part after 2nd if?? Can i directly return to else?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `else` applies to the **last** `if` unless there is an intervening `fi`.

Comment: Sorry i missed fi. Otherwise bash throws error

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to jump from the "error" message line to beyond the "else" arm, but this would be messy in bash.

A better way would be to set a flag if the correct response is received, and use that flag to report success or failuer. For example:

```
got_response=Y
http_status= some response
if [[ "$http_status" -ne 200 ]]; then
   # curl command to check the response
   http_status= some response

   if [[ "$http_status" -ne 200 ]]; then
       # curl command to check the response
       http_status= some response

       if [[ "$http_status" -ne 200 ]]; then
           got_response=N
       fi
   fi
fi

if [[ $got_response = "Y" ]]; then
    echo "You got the response"
else
    echo "Some error. Please try again"
fi
```

There are other potential improvements, such as using a "while" loop to repeat the requests (making it much easier to change the number of attempts).

Note that I've moved your "http_status=some response" lines up one - you need one before the first "if" test, and you don't want one in your code when you are reporting the error.